# How to tell what is blocking internet (download) on cloud server

Tags: networking, yum, centos5

Background: My employer is using a cloud-based database server through a service called Rackspace. This server is accessed by our other servers via ssh. Our network admins are unreachable for the next week, we have very little documentation regarding our custom configurations, and Rackspace has recommended backing up all servers due to a restart they need to perform in the next few days.

The issue: The server in question, almost certainly by intention, for security reasons, is unable to download content from the internet. I need to use yum (the package manager) to install the backup agent that Rackspace uses, so that I can backup the server. But yum gives an error that it cannot connect to the repos, and when I try to ping google or any well-known outside site, I get 100% packet loss. How do I find out if this is a configuration in Rackspace (I have scanned through their documentation and cannot find anything that seems relevant.) or somewhere in the machine?

Output of `iptables -L -n`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
#[... A long list of ACCEPT rules edited out for brevity]

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
#[... A long list of ACCEPT rules edited out for brevity]
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: Try iptables -L -n and see if the OUTPUT chain has a DROP policy or if it contains REJECT or DROP rules.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the problem is that I need network access in order to perform software installations, so that I can use our cloud service's backup tools. I don't mean to assume anything. I actually am asking for advice on where I should look, what I should check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily open your firewall with

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -j ACCEPT
```

which adds the ACCEPT rule BEFORE anything else (the 1 means "at index 1"). Make the yum updates and installs, then close the firewall again with

```
iptables -D INPUT 1
```

Another solution would be to temporarily delete the first rule with

```
iptables -D INPUT 1
```

and then restore the firewall orginal state with

```
service iptables restart
```

(this last command works only on Redhat and Redhat like systems).

Comment: I have just read up on this, and it appears that the `-I` flag would add the `ACCEPT` rule *after* the existing `REJECT` rule, where it wouldn't effect anything. So I'd actually want to *remove* the last rule, and add it back later, versus adding an `ACCEPT` rule and removing that later, correct?

Comment: Ok, editing the IP tables (I found it easier to directly edit the file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` with `vi` than to use insert/delete commands), and restarting the service with `service iptables restart` did the trick! I made the updates and secured it back up. Thanks for the help!